# Action bar Sherlock error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

While trying to create a library project using the library folder in ActionbarSherlock, I keep getting a "MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved to a variable" error. 
I have googled for hours now, and am not able to find a solution. 
Any clues on what might be causing this will be a great help?

The error is in ActionBarSherlock.java on line 669.

Comment: try going into the [freenode server](http://webchat.freenode.net/) to the #android-dev channel, and ask Jake Wharton, he wrote ActionbarSherlock

Comment: Sounds like you're not compiling with Android 4.0+ as the library requires.

Comment: I am compiling with Android 4.0.3

Answer (score 2):

You should set your build target to API level 15.

Edit:

The solution is to use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: Build target is set to API level 15, and minSDK is level 7

Comment: try ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT... any luck?

Comment: ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT is working. Thanks a ton. I wonder why this error came about?